# Abstract measure (product measure)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X_1,m_1,\mu_1),(X_2,m,\mu_2)$

$E^{x_2}=\{x_1\in X_1;(x_1,x_2)\in E\}$

If $E$ is an arbitrary measurable set in X, then $\int_{X_2}\mu_1(E^{x_2})d\mu_2=(\mu_1*\mu_2)(E)$

This propostion is ture???

I think that this propostion is not ture... I want to find counter example.

Answer (score 0):

If, by "an arbitrary measurable set in $X$" you meant " an arbitrary measurable set in $X_1 \times X_2$ with respect to the product measure induced" (and I also assume $\mu_1 * \mu_2$ is the product measure), then yes this is correct. In fact this is a corollary of Tonelli's theorem.

To see that, you can just use the usual trick, rewrite the measure of $E^{x_2}$ as the integral of its indicator function:
$$\int_{X_2} \mu_1(E^{x_2})d\mu_2 = \int_{X_2} \int_{X_1} \chi_E(x_1, x_2) d\mu_1 d\mu_2$$
and hence the claim follows from Tonelli's theorem.

If however the set is only measurable with respect to either one of the $X_i$ then it is not true in general. Taking the product of a measurable and a non-measurable set will not yield a measurable set for instance...